# Split the large file and group the split files into sub directories

Tags: linux, shell-script, split

In a Directory, Find the files having size greater than 5GB and split them as 2GB files each, then group the slit files of 5 files into separate directories.

If I have a file with 20GB in my current directory, the slpit it into 10 files of 2GB, the make 4 sub-directories, each of them having 5 splits of 2GB  files

Any shell script help

This is what I have done

```
for myfile in *
        do
                if [ -n "$(find "$myfile" -size +5G)" ]; then
                         split -b 2G $myfile /tmp/split-file
                fi
        done
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @RomeoNinov plz check

Comment: Check the man page of `split` command to see why this will mess the things.